# Android Studio 3.2 Canary 14 Github integration

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, github-api, android-studio-3.2

I just updated to the new 3.2 Canary build of Android Studio and everything seems to work fine, except for Github integration.

When I try to push or pull through the UI, I get the following error:

```
Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.askPassword(GitAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.http.GitAskPassApp.main(GitAskPassApp.java:68)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendRequest(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:231)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:90)
```

However, the test tool under *Settings* **>** *Version Control* **>** *GitHub* works perfectly. So does the console git. And so did the 3.1 AS I used before.

Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: What "Auth Type" do you use?

Comment: It tried both (Password and Token) and both work in the Settings - the Test button returns green result, for token it gives back the correct user name. But the VCS ui does not work for either.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any ideas?

Comment: No, nothing at all :( I was able to use it through the built-in Terminal, but the experience was not so great, as I heavily rely on changesets. So my solution was going back to 3.1 :-(

Comment: @Kelevandos You can use 3.2 Cannary 8, that's the one I'm using, Github integration still works but we end up loosing those new amazing features, I already opened a issue for them, hope we get a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be solved in AS 3.2 **Canary 16**, so just update.

Answer (score 4):

Just go in settings->Version control->Git and check the credential helper box.